# JavaScript recursion returns intermediate results rather than the final result

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have this JavaScript code where the rec() function is called by itself. The intent with this code is to loop through HTML-like text and replace all occurrences of the regex "IMG(.*)tid".

Once it has processed the string it should output the final version of the string in the "newText" variable (on line 5).

```js
var text = '<IMG tid="302293901" title="test"><P></P><IMG tid="302293901" title="test">';
alert("source text: " + text);

var newText = rec(text);
alert("final source text: " + newText);

function rec(str) {
  var i = str.search("IMG(.*)tid");
  alert("value of i: " + i);
  if (i > -1) {
    str = str.replace("IMG", "BLA");
    alert("modified source text: " + str);
    rec(str);
  }
  return str;
}
```

When this code runs it does modify the source string in the "text" variable, replacing all occurrences of "IMG" with "BLA". During it's execution the function displays the expected final string that looks as shown below.

[image: expected final results]

However the problem with this is that the alert box on line 5 does not return the results shown above, but an intermediary result (where only one of the "IMG" entries has been replaced).

The returned string is shown below.

[image: actual final results]

So this code is probably incorrectly structured but in what way?

Comment: I don't know if you are studying recursion or something like that, but: do you know you can solve this specific problem using RegExp's ?

Comment: Why aren't you returning the result of the recursive call? Ie `return rec(str)`

Comment: thanks @MarcoS, yes in this case I just wanted to understand why this recursion behaves like this.

Comment: Thanks @CrescentFresh for pointing that out as it does fix the issue as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run rec again from within rec, you're not doing anything with the returned result. You need to change it to `str = rec(str)`

Comment: aargh duh yes u r correct. That was rather dumb of me. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value of `rec`...

```
function rec(str) {
  var i = str.search("IMG(.*)tid");
  alert("value of i: " + i);
  if (i > -1) {
    str = str.replace("IMG", "BLA");
    alert("modified source text: " + str);
    return rec(str);
  }
  return str;
}
```